# Why C++ template type match doesn't retrieve reference qualifier '&'?

Tags: c++, templates, types, reference, match

I've got the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
template<class T> void f(T t) { 
    t += 1; 
}
template<class T> void g(T &t) {
    t += 10;
}
int main()
{
    int n=0;
    int&i=n;
    f(i);
    g(i);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that because `i` is a reference to `n`, so I expect that the template function `f` should get `int&` for template type `T`. But in fact it doesn't. The output of the program is `10`, not `11` as I expected.

So my question is, for `f`, why `T` matches `int` but not `int&` of variable `i`? What's the rule behind here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template deduction never deduces a reference type unless you use a forwarding reference.  So your calls to `f` and `g` both deduce `T` as `int`.

Also, an expression never has reference type. `i` and `n` as expressions are identical. They have type `int` and value category *lvalue*.

The code `int n = 0; int &i = n;` is exactly the same as `int i = 0; int &n = i;`, except for [decltype(1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype). It creates one object with two names, `i` and `n`.

Even if you did use a forwarding reference in your code, e.g. `template<class T>void h(T&&t)`, the calls `h(i)` and `h(n)` would deduce the same way.

This symmetry is why you see many comments on the [What is a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) megathread  present references as I have just now,  and we consider the description "a reference is a pointer that automatically dereferences" to be misleading.